# How to use Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM) topic with AWS SNS

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I want to establish a structure being the organization based. each organization has a topic on FCM.

If an organization wants to send a push notification:

it will request my backend via organization_id and a topic name and I shall trigger AWS SNS with the payload.

But I don't know and find whether can I request directly an FCM topic.

Comment: It seems your question is too broad to tackle. Maybe you can share what steps have you done and what specific blocker are you experiencing. You can read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want to use FCM topics specifically. But if that is not the case, then you can use topics in AWS SNS itself. You can create SNS topics for your organisations. Then, your device endpoints can subscribe to your SNS topics, and you can send notifications to those topics.

Here is the link for more details - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-topicmobile.html